# Перестает выполняться код в php после цикла

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который берет данные из базы и формирует файл xml.
Обработка цикла занимает несколько минут(до 10), происходит запись в файл порядка 200 000 строк. А код ниже перестает выполняться. Вызываю mail(), а письмо не приходит. Если взять меньше данных, чтобы цикл успел выполниться быстрее, то все работает.
Время на выполнения скрипта стоит 3600 секунд. Что не дает работать коду дальше?

Comment: возможно, скрипт нужно запускать не с под вебсервера, а напрямую, в консоли (или кроном). Код дальше может не выполнятся, так как скрипт истратил всю доступную память, выделенную под него.

Comment: Каким образом вы запускаете скрипт (CLI, встроенный PHP сервер, веб-сервер)? Если веб-сервер, то какой именно? Так же уточните что за параметр вы установили 3600 секунд? Ограничения есть как у PHP, так на веб-сервере.

Comment: Запускаю кроном, веб-сервер apache. Настройки PHP max_execution_time 3600, memory_limit 1024M

Comment: Попробуйте этот параметр посмотреть http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: Замерил memory_get_usage, получилось почти 200МБ

Comment: А случайно код не написан так, что он все строки в память загружает, а потом с массива пишет на диск? В этом случае есть смысл переписать код так, что бы он читал по немного (возможно даже по одной записи) и писал на диск по строке-две за раз. (на большинстве дисков оптимально писать кусками по 4 килобайта).

Comment: Увелечение timeout не помогло. Да, так и есть, все сразу пишет.

Comment: В логах апача много записей [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open %file% - Too many open files

Comment: А что у вас в кроне написано? Если url, то сделайте консольную команду и пропишите ее в крон. Не трогайте таймауты.

Answer (score 2):

> 200 000 строк

Это детский объём для PHP. Ну запись разумеется желательно делать буфферизовано - например по 1к строк(накопилось 1к => записали => накопилось 1к => записали => ... => записали остатки), чтобы в меру ушатывать жёсткий диск и расходовать оперативку - это 30 секунд на среднем железе.

> Обработка цикла занимает несколько минут(до 10)

10 минут - это конечно не нормально для 200к строк в файл. И вероятно при таком времени выполнения ваш скрипт отваливается по таймауту. Чтобы не отваливался - пропишите, например:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 3600/*1 час*/);
```

Но лучше конечно сначала оптимизируйте код.